# json_decode() - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: php, json, api, codeigniter

So I decided to make my own helper in Codeigniter to get JSON files and save PokeAPI calls as JSON.

The save JSON method I created works fine:

```
if ( ! function_exists('saveJson')) {
    function saveJson($file, $data) {
      $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
      fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
      fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

However the getJSON function works very randomly. It works for fetching certain files but others it throws this error: **Message: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given.** (all json files are the same format)

getJSON function:

```
if ( ! function_exists('getJson')) {
    function getJson($file) {
      $json = file_get_contents($file);
      $data = json_decode($json, true);
      $pkm = json_decode($data, true);
      return $pkm;
    }
}
```

Its odd, I have to decode the JSON twice or can I cannot access the array in my views.

My model and controller for further depth on the issue:
Model function example:

```
function getPokemonById($id) {
      $filepath = './assets/jsonsaves/pokemoncalls/'. $id. '.json';
      if(file_exists($filepath)) {
        $pokemonByIdData = getJson($filepath);
      } else {
        $url = $this->pokemonApiAddress.$id.'/';
        $response = Requests::get($url);
        saveJson($filepath, $response);
        $pokemonByIdData = json_decode($response->body, true);
      }
      return $pokemonByIdData;
    }
```

Controller function example:

```
public function viewPokemon($id) {
        $singlePokemon['pokemon'] = $this->pokemon_model->getPokemonById($id);
        $singlePokemon['species'] = $this->pokemon_model->getPokemonSpecies($id);
        $data['thepokemon'] = $this->pokemon_model->getAllPokemon();
    $this->load->view('template/header', $data);
        $this->load->view('pokemonpage', $singlePokemon);
    $this->load->view('template/footer');
    }
```

So there is some variation in my JSON file. In one JSON file that does not work it has, at the beginning:

```
{"body":"{\"forms\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/pokeapi.co\\\/api\\\/v2\\\/pokemon-form\\\/142\\\/\",\"name\":\"aerodactyl\"}],...
```

However this one works:

```
"{\"forms\":[{\"url\":\"https:\\\/\\\/pokeapi.co\\\/api\\\/v2\\\/pokemon-form\\\/6\\\/\",\"name\":\"charizard\"}],...
```

Comment: Can you post an example of your JSON file's contents?

Comment: `$data` is already decoded json, why are you trying to decode it again? `$data = json_decode($json, true); $pkm = json_decode($data, true);` - this would only work if the first json_decode returns a string, which doesn't make much sense to decode anyway?

Comment: As a general rule of thumb: Every action you do in your save method you also do in your load method, in reverse. You do **one** encode in your save method, you do **one** decode in your load method.

Comment: @barni the JSON files are quite large in content, is there anywhere I could host them?

Comment: @ccKep I have to decode it twice or for some reason I cannot access the data in my view arrays, I get this error otherwise: Message: Illegal string offset 'id'

Comment: Your 2nd one is literally 1 string, which contains json data. You should take a look how you're getting your data in that case. The point still stands: If you're doing more steps in your load than in your save function you're bound to get errors.

Comment: @ccKep thank you for the advice. I removed the JSON encode from the save method as I the response from the API was already JSON anyway. this allowed me to remove one of the JSON decodes from the getJSON method. Seems to be working now! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue thanks to @ccKep.

I removed the JSON encode from my saveJSON function like so:

```
if ( ! function_exists('saveJson')) {
    function saveJson($file, $data) {
      $fp = fopen($file, 'w');
      fwrite($fp, $data);
      fclose($fp);
    }
}
```

And then removed the second json_decode from my getJSON function:

```
if ( ! function_exists('getJson')) {
    function getJson($file) {
      $json = file_get_contents($file);
      $data = json_decode($json, true);
      return $data;
    }
}
```

This fixed the errors I was receiving.